# When I try to update the link to external data in datawrapper using API, the link doesn't get updated

Tags: python, charts, get

I'm playing with [datawrapper](https://datawrapper.de), and I'm trying to change the `externalData` value, and it is not updating. Well, it updates the first one, but unless I delete it afterwards through the website, it doesn't get replaced after doing the second call.

Here's a small python script (you'd need an ID for a chart, and an API token - which is free).

```
import requests

# The URL of the chart
url = "https://api.datawrapper.de/v3/charts/{id}"

# The headers for your request
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}


payload = {"externalData": "https://example.com/something2.csv"}

# Make the PATCH request
response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

# Print the response


print('External data:', response.text)
```